# Why is force_encoding("BINARY") used here?

Tags: ruby

When we install Rails, we get this `rails` "executable":

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

I'm wondering what the point of doing `force_encoding("BINARY")` is on that String. What possible values could it be that `force_encoding` is necessary? I would think that people would only specify versions using numbers and letters here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a rails specific thing - it's a wrapper  rubygems will generate for any ruby executable in a gem. The call to `force_encoding` was added in [6bf71914](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/6bf71914de25776a6725eceae4046cd81c5ede45)

The reason for the change is that the first argument might not be a version at all - we want to test if it is a version, but it could be anything and we don't want the regex check to blow up. For example some executables accept a list of file names as arguments, and those file names could be invalid in the default external encoding used by ruby.

There is a bit more discussion on the [issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/307) which prompted this change.